# Error message on plotting a solution curve for an ODE solved with DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to plot the solution curves for an ODE.

This is what I do:

```
sol = Flatten[DSolve[y'[x] == y[x]^3/x^3 + y[x]/x + 1, y[x], x]]

Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1}], {x, -7, 7}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

But I get an error message after a long time of calculation saying

*This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.*

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: If you just run DSolve[] it gives the solution implicitly in terms of Solve[] (ie it gives x(y) and not y(x) as usual) and a highly non-linear and non-algebraic equation involving ArcTan[] and Log[] which cannot be solved analytically to go from x(y)->y(x), so it gets stuck there. The message simply means that the final equation cannot be solved with the tricks Solve[] knows ;-)

Comment: To make the plot you could either use NDSolve[] or take the equation in the Solve[] and solve that numerically. Surprisingly, one may write down the analytic solution to x(y), but inverting it to find y(x) is tough. If you're happy with x(y) and inverting it numerically, that could also be a solution.

Comment: A series solution at point `x=1` with 5 terms : `AsymptoticDSolveValue[y'[x] == y[x]^3/x^3 + y[x]/x + 1, 
  y[x], {x, 1, 5}] /. C[1] -> 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ContourPlot` to plot an implicit solution. Generally, I'd think the plot domain needs to be determined by inspection.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[
  C[1] /. Block[{Solve}, ReplacePart[sol, 2 -> {C[1]}]] /.
   y[x] -> y],
 {x, 0, 1.1}, {y, -0.2, 10}, Contours -> {{1}}, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

It's worth considering that `ContourPlot` can easily plot multiple solutions:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[
  C[1] /. Block[{Solve}, ReplacePart[sol, 2 -> {C[1]}]] /.
   y[x] -> y],
 {x, 0, 3}, {y, -2, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> C[1]], {After, Top}]]
```

[image]

---

*Alternative*

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[
  Block[{Solve}, 
    Replace[sol, Verbatim[Solve][eq_, __] :> eq]
    ] /. {C[1] -> 1, y[x] -> y}],
 {x, 0, 1.1}, {y, -0.2, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to explain more why this ode has no explicit solution.

Solve
\begin{gather*}
\boxed{y^{\prime}-\frac{y^{3}}{x^{3}}-\frac{y}{x}-1=0}
\end{gather*}

In canonical form, the ODE is
\begin{align*}
             y' &= F(x,y)\\ 
                          &= \frac{x^{3}+y \,x^{2}+y^{3}}{x^{3}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
This is a homogeneous ode. Since this ode is homogeneous, it is converted to separable ODE using the substitution
$u=\frac{y}{x}$, or $y=ux$. Hence
$$
              \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}y}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}= \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}u}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}x + u
$$

Applying the transformation $y=ux$ to the above ODE in (1) gives
\begin{align*}
            \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}u}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}x + u &= u^{3}+u +1\\ 
            \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}u}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}} &= \frac{u^{3}+1}{x}
\end{align*}
This is separable. It can be written as
$$
      \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}u}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}} = f( x) g(u) 
$$
Where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(u)=u^{3}+1$. Therefore
$$
               \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}u}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}} = \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \left(u^{3}+1\right)
$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
                \frac{1}{u^{3}+1}\mathop{\mathrm{d}u}&= \frac{1}{x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\\   
                   \int \frac{1}{u^{3}+1}\mathop{\mathrm{d}u}&= \int \frac{1}{x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}
\end{align*}
Integrating gives
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\ln \left(u^{2}-u +1\right)}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{3}\, \arctan \left(\frac{\left(2 u -1\right) \sqrt{3}}{3}\right)}{3}+\frac{\ln \left(u +1\right)}{3} = \ln \left(x \right)+c_{1}
\end{align*}

$u$ in the above solution is replaced back to $y$ using $u=\frac{y}{x}$
which results in the solution
$$
 -\frac{\ln \left(\frac{y \left(x \right)^{2}}{x^{2}}-\frac{y \left(x \right)}{x}+1\right)}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{3}\, \arctan \left(\frac{\left(\frac{2 y \left(x \right)}{x}-1\right) \sqrt{3}}{3}\right)}{3}+\frac{\ln \left(\frac{y \left(x \right)}{x}+1\right)}{3} = \ln \left(x \right)+c_{1}
$$
There is no explicit solution in $y$ as not possible to analytically solve for $y$ from the above.